# Disable a plugin for a module on Symfony

Tags: symfony1

I am developing an application using Symfony 1.4. Is it posible to disable a plugin just for one module?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's probably possible by hacking around, but why would you do this? Plugins tend to be 'larger' in scope than modules, and generally are only invoked per module if you choose to. Can you elaborate on which plugin and the module's purpose?

Comment: I agree with Raise, you may need this but it doesn't make sense. Generally, you simply wouldn't use the plugin functionality in a module to avoid it. If you're referring to sfDoctrineGuard, there's a specific way to disable security for selected modules.

Comment: Furthermore, plugins are even supposed to be shared between applications, not even modules! If you are concerned about speeding down your module due to a enabled plugin, don't be.

Comment: Let's say you have an action that generates non-html code like an xml or csv file. Many plugins that alter the view, still put code in the output even if has_layout is false, or the app uses renderText() and has no template at all. Disabling the plugin for the module or specific action would make perfect sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody,

Finally I solved it changing all plugin configurations from my actions.class.php using sfConfig::set() method.

Comment: Well, we could have offered that - but I think we were hoping to avoid an ugly hack in preference of a better understanding of the plugin system. I'm not sure your answer benefits anyone :(

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use plugin, but don't want to use module he provides, just don't enable this module. You are not obligated to do that.